# Why is the energy probability different from its speed probability in the Maxwell-Boltzmann Distribution?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, statistical-mechanics, speed

I know this has been asked before [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/329395/why-energy-corresponding-to-most-probable-speed-is-not-equal-to-most-probable-en) and I understand how the formula changes when the Maxwell-Boltzmann Distribution (MBD) is written in terms of speed. But I am trying to understand this more intrinsically.

I don't understand why the probability for a particle with energy $E \geq E+dE$ is different from the probability of the speed that belongs to that energy range.

The answer that's being said (I think) is because when the MBD is written in terms of energy, a $dE$ covers a different number of particles than a $dv$ does when it is written in terms of speed.

However, I have a struggle with that answer because of the following:

Starting from a certain speed $v_0$, a $dv$ covers the number of particles that have speeds between $v_0 \geq v_0 + dv$. Those particles would have energies between $\frac{1}{2}mv_0^2 \geq \frac{1}{2}m(v_0 + dv)^2$ which 
is exactly what $dE$ is.
Thus, $dE$ covers those same number of particles that have those speeds $v_0 \geq v_0 + dv$.

How would the number of particles differ?

Comment: The way you wrote the question makes me think that you have not unterstood the answer given to the linked question. The probabilities are equal. The probability densities are not.

Comment: @Paul You're saying the probability within $E_0 \geq E_0 + dE$ is the same as the probability within $v_0 \geq v_0 + dv$ where $v_0$ corresponds to $E_0$? It gives me different answers. The densities however are the same; the density at $v_0$ is the same as the density at $\frac{1}{2}mv_0^2$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $E_0 \geq E_0 + dE$. I guess you mean the interval between $E_0$ and $E_0 + dE$?

Comment: Either way, maybe take a look at Wikipedia. The distribution of energies is actually found by imposing that the probability (integral over probability density) is the same. You must have some kind of missunderstanding/error.

Comment: @Paul You're right, I got it mixed up. The densities are different but the probabilities within $dE$ and $dv$ are the same. It does surprise me though why then the most probable speed is different from the most probable energy since the number of particles should be the same whether it be in terms of speed $v_0$ or energy $E_0$.

Comment: That is why the value of the density is not physical. But if you take an integral, even if you make the interval very short, the probabilities will e the same on both sides. It is "just" one of those peculiar, non-intuitive things mathematics brings with it. One get's used to it and then stops thinking about them ;)

Comment: @Paul The most probable speed density is $v_{max}=\sqrt{\frac{2k_BT}{m}}$ and the most probable energy density is $E_{max} = \frac{k_BT}{2}$.
So you're saying that
$$P(\frac{k_BT}{2}) \cdot dE = P(\sqrt{\frac{2k_BT}{m}})\cdot dv$$
It does not give the same answer. Notice that they are **not** related to each other as $E_{max}=\frac{1}{2}mv_{max}^2$.

Comment: No this is not what I'm saying. I'm saying that $\int_{E_o-\epsilon}^{E_0+\epsilon} dE f(E) = \int_{v(E_0 - \epsilon)}^{v(E_0 + \epsilon)} dv f(v)$ Which is a very easy statement to make. But it means that if you e.g. choose $E_0$ to be $E_\text{max}$, you will get the same on both sides, irrespective of the maxima of the densities not being the same. Calling the density $P$ is misleading, as it is NOT a probability. The probability for any single point is zero, as the integral over an interval of zero width is zero.

Comment: People will talk about $E_\text{max}$ and $v_\text{max}$, because they set the scale. And you are able to describe other quantities in terms of them. Other than that they are physically irrelevant. Keep in mind that the distributions are not symmetric. Therefore the max is not the same as the mean.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is confusing whats the difference between probabilities and probability densities. If you write the the probability distribution expressed with velocities you get $$ 1 = \int_0^\infty f(v)dv.$$ If you want to calculate the probability of a particle having velocity in some finite interval $a < v <b$ you get $$ P(a<v<b) = \int_a^b f(v)dv.$$ If you make a change of variable to energy $E = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$ you get $$ P(a<v<b) = \int_{ma^2/2}^{mb^2/2} f(v(E)) \frac{dv}{dE}dE.$$ Now you can in particular choose $a=v_0$ and $b=v_0+dv$ and the $\textit{probabilities}$ of being in interval $v_0<v<v_0 +dv$ is equal to $mv_0^2/2< E < m(v_0+dv)^2/2$. This just follows from making a variable change in an integral. However, the probability densities of having velocity $v$ and energy $E=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ are not equal. This is because the probability density of having energy $E$ is not just $f(v(E))$ but you get a contribution from the derivative $\frac{dv}{dE}$.

So, in general the probability densities are not equal $$f(v) \neq f(v(E)) \frac{dv}{dE}.$$ But when you integrate the probability density you get equal probabilities for corresponding velocity and energy intervals.

Comment: You're right, I got it all mixed up. It is the _densities_ that are different. Is there a way to extrapolate this to explain why the _most probable_ speed is different from the _most probable_ energy? What is exactly wrong with the following statement:

**If the largest number of particles has an energy between $E_0 \geq E_0 + dE$, then that same large number of particles have the speed $v_0 \geq dv$ that corresponds to that energy $E_0 \geq E_0 + dE$**

Comment: The most probable speed density is $v_{max}=\sqrt{\frac{2k_BT}{m}}$ and the most probable energy density is $E_{max} = \frac{k_BT}{2}$. They're not equal as you said but if you say that integrating them gives the same probability then that means that
$$P(\frac{k_BT}{2}) \cdot dE = P(\sqrt{\frac{2k_BT}{m}})\cdot dv$$
But they do not give the same probabiity. Notice that they are **not** related to each other:  $E_{max}\neq\frac{1}{2}mv_{max}^2$

Comment: The most probable speed is different from the most probable energy just because you get the derivative factor $\frac{dv}{dE}$. Why the probability densities are different is simply a consequence of that the probabilities has to be equal. The probabilities is what is ''real'' in some sense, what you can measure. The probability densities is defined as ''what you integrate over to get the probability''. So that the probability densities have different maxima can never be observed because you always measure the probabilities.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot. One last question if you don't mind. The answer in this link https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/329395/why-energy-corresponding-to-most-probable-speed-is-not-equal-to-most-probable-en explains that the discrepancy between the probability densities being a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ is because $$\mathrm{d}v \propto \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{d}E$$
I can't derive this proportionality. How is this derived?

Comment: I would say that this proportionality does not say much because you have a bunch of other factors as well. To derive the correct, and general expression take $$E = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 $$ and differentiate w.r.t. $v$ $$\frac{dE}{dv} = mv \implies dE = mv dv.$$ Then you can rearrange this in lots of ways if you want.

Comment: Yes I have derived it that way indeed, and with that I noticed that the proportionality given in the link is actually incorrect. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

$$ E = \frac 1 2 m v^2$$

$$ dE = mv dv$$

so:

$$ \frac{dE}{E} = \frac{mv dv}{\frac 1 2 m v^2}$$

$$\frac{dE}{E} = 2 \frac{dv}{v} $$

Or in the terms you presented:

$$ \frac 1 2 m(v_0 + dv)^2 = \frac 1 2 m(v_0 + 2mv_0dv)$$

(where $dv^2 \rightarrow 0$, has been used):

$$ = E_0 + mdv = E_0 + 2dE \ne E_0 + dE$$

Comment: Wait, isn't $\frac{1}{2}m(v_0 + dv)^2 = \frac{1}{2}m(v_0^2 + 2v_0dv)$ (where $dv^2 = 0$ as you proposed)? Thus, meaning $$\frac{1}{2}m(v_0^2 + 2v_0dv) = \frac{1}{2}mv_0^2 + mv_0dv =  E_0 + dE$$